# Django deployment with Vercel error after succesful deployment: Serverless Function Invocation Failed

Tags: django, database, sqlite, vercel

Tried to deploy my django project on vercel which was successfully deployed but then I get this error when I try to view my pages:

```
[ERROR] ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.9.0 or later is required (found 3.7.17).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/vc__handler__python.py", line 159, in vc_handler
    response = Response.from_app(__vc_module.app, environ)
  File "/var/task/werkzeug/wrappers/base_response.py", line 287, in from_app
    return cls(*_run_wsgi_app(app, environ, buffered))
  File "/var/task/werkzeug/test.py", line 1096, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/var/task/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 131, in __call__
    signals.request_started.send(sender=self.__class__, environ=environ)
  File "/var/task/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "/var/task/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/var/task/django/db/__init__.py", line 27, in reset_queries
    for conn in connections.all():
  File "/var/task/django/utils/connection.py", line 76, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/var/task/django/utils/connection.py", line 76, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/var/task/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/var/task/django/db/utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/var/task/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 73, in <module>
    check_sqlite_version()
  File "/var/task/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 68, in check_sqlite_version
    raise ImproperlyConfigured( .
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error because I configured to used an external postgres DB on railway but I get an error for SQLite. This is my database config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.parse(config('DB_URL')),
    'postgres': {
        'ENGINE': config('DB_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': config('DB_PORT')
    }
}
```

This is my requirements.txt content if necessary:

```
Django==3.2.2
django-cloudinary-storage==0.3.0
python-magic==0.4.25
python-decouple==3.6
gunicorn==20.1.0
psycopg2-binary==2.9.6
Pillow==8.0.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
whitenoise==5.3.0
django-jazzmin==2.6.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
```

Please has anyone run into this issue before or knows how to resolve this issue?

I have tried resetting my database configuration just to be sure. My project works fine o development